# Write JSON string into a JSON file in a proper format without using inbuilt methods or third party libraries

Tags: c#, json

I have a text file which contains Data and another text file that contains data fields. I am able to read in the the data and data fields into separate array

I have managed to convert it into JsonFormat. But when I am writing it in the json file it is not coming properly formatted ike a json data would. How would it come into a proper format? Also I don't want to use serialization or third party libs.

My input data file contains 102 lines where 1st and last can be ignored. Each line corresponds to one record. So it has around 100 records. Each record has 150 fields seperated by |.

Sample record:

928338219||3HY83||A|Z5|20030917|20160629|20150630|20150630|FEDERAL HIGHWAY ADMINISTRATION||OFFICE OF ACQUISITIION AND GRANTS MANAGEMENT||1200 NEW JERSEY AVE SE||WASHINGTON|DC|20590|0001|USA|98|19720101|0930||2A|||0003|2R~NG~VW|926120|0001|926120N|0000||||1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE, SE|ROOM E65-101|WASHINGTON|20590|0001|USA|DC|FRANK WALTOS||WALTOS||1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE, SE|ROOM E65-312|WASHINGTON|20590|0001|USA|DC|2023664205|||2023663705|Frank.Waltos@dot.gov|FRANK||WALTOS||1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE SE|ROOM E65-312|WASHINGTON|20590|0001|USA|DC|2023664205|||2023663705|Frank.Waltos@dot.gov|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||FRANK||WALTOS||1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE SE|ROOM E65-312|WASHINGTON|20590|0001|USA|DC|2023664205|||2023663705|Frank.Waltos@dot.gov|JASON||JOHNSON||1200 NEW JERSEY AVENUE SE||WASHINGTON|20590|0001|USA|DC|2023665880|||2023663705|jason.johnson@dot.gov|0000||N||0000|||0000||!end

The DataFields file contains the 150 fields
sample:

DUNS
DUNS+4
CAGE CODE
DODAAC
SAM EXTRACT CODE
PURPOSE OF REGISTRATION
REGISTRATION DATE
EXPIRATION DATE

I am expecting the records to be written something like this

```
 {
  "DUNS": "070815200",
  "DUNS+4": "",
  "CAGE CODE": "7HEG5",
  "DODAAC": "",
  "SAM EXTRACT CODE": "A",
  "PURPOSE OF REGISTRATION": "Z2",
  "REGISTRATION DATE": "20151113",
  "EXPIRATION DATE": "20161112",
  "LAST UPDATE DATE": "20151123"
 }
```

right now they are getting written without any formatting like this

{"DataFile1" :[{"DUNS":"928338219","DUNS+4":""}.

I have checked my JSON string in Jsonlint and it is a valid JSON

```
public void convertToJSONsyntax( string [] data, string [] dataFields) 
    {
  string[] splitData = new string[150];
        var JSONSyntaxString = "{\"DataFile1\" :[";
        //var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONSyntaxString);
        for (int i=0;i<data.Length; i++) 
        {
            JSONSyntaxString += "{";
            splitData = data[i].Split('|');
            for(int j = 0; j < dataFields.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == dataFields.Length - 1)
                {
                    JSONSyntaxString += "\"" + dataFields[j] + "\":\"" + splitData[j] + "\"";
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONSyntaxString += "\"" + dataFields[j] + "\":\"" + splitData[j] + "\",";
                }
            }
            if (i == data.Length - 1)
            {
                JSONSyntaxString += "}";
            }
            else
            {
                JSONSyntaxString += "},";
            }
        }
        JSONSyntaxString = JSONSyntaxString + "]}";
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\OutputData.json", JSONSyntaxString);
```

Comment: This screams school assignment. 
Show us what you have tried already, and ask a specific question as to what you need to do, in order to obtain your goal. 
This is not a work-work service.

Comment: unless it is homework, which you should tell us, you should **never** write your own JSON.  there's too many wrong implementations of it out there, already, and having to deal with one of them is a huge headache each time. that being said, the best way to learn how to write JSON is to carefully read the specifications and walk through them step by step.

Comment: It is homework. I am just trying to understand what my next steps should be. I am fairly new to C# and JSON

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  I have almost completed it. just can't get it to write to proper format. please see the edited question

Comment: @MortenBork. Sorry about that. I don't use stackoverflow that much. I have edited the question

Comment: @Sidarth

We need to see the input content, or at least a sample of it, so we can see what is being used for testing. We cannot determine why your result doesn't match your expectation, when you don't provide us with what you are expecting? 

Should it be 100% JSON valid? What about arrays in JSON? 
So far it seems you are only handling Property names and values? 

So again: 
Provide a reproducable code example. So we can help you out properly. Consider reading the "how to ask a question guide".
Also you are using ´|´ as a delimiter? If we have a sample, we could verifty it is used?

Comment: I just ran and built your code on my local machine. 

If I use the following data: 

string[] data = { "SomeValueForKey|SomeValueForKey2", "SomeValueForKeyForAnotherItem|SomeOtherValueForAnotherItem2"};
            string[] dataFields = { "Key", "Key2" };

As input, your function works. 
So you need to give us more info.

Why does it not produce the result you want? 
What do you use for input? 
What do you expect as output. 
And where does your actual result, differ from your expected result.

Comment: @MortenBork. Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) Okay, so when you write text to a file. And you wish it to display with text formatting you have to keep track of the formatting itself.

Let us say you have a tab indent, you would like to apply? Or a newline?

You have to write that into the text formatting.

Something like this:

```
 string[] splitData = new string[150];
            var JSONSyntaxString = "{\"\tDataFile1\" :[\r\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                JSONSyntaxString += "\t\t{\r\n";
                splitData = data[i].Split('|');
                for (int j = 0; j < dataFields.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j == dataFields.Length - 1)
                    {
                        JSONSyntaxString += "\t\t\t\"" + dataFields[j] + "\":\"" + splitData[j] + "\"";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JSONSyntaxString += "\t\t\t\"" + dataFields[j] + "\":\"" + splitData[j] + "\",\r\n";
                    }
                }
                if (i == data.Length - 1)
                {
                    JSONSyntaxString += "\r\n\t\t}\r\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONSyntaxString += "\r\n\t\t},\r\n";
                }
            }
            JSONSyntaxString = JSONSyntaxString + "]}";
            File.WriteAllText("E:\\Test\\OutputData.json", JSONSyntaxString);
```

\t = tab

\r\n = Newline.

With my improptu test data that gave me this result:

```
{"  DataFile1" :[
        {
            "Key":"SomeValueForKey",
            "Key2":"SomeValueForKey2"
        },
        {
            "Key":"SomeValueForKeyForAnotherItem",
            "Key2":"SomeOtherValueForAnotherItem2"
        }
]}
```

I hope that this is enough help to get you over the finishline yourself :)